# SSID name truncated on Android version at least up to 4.1.2

Tags: android

I don't know if it's a known issue but I register the connections realized by my application on my server and the SSID where these connections were made from.
And I see the SSID name is truncated on some Androïd version, in particular Android version at least up to 4.1.2.

Here are some of my records:

```
"6", ... ,"Lozere Wireless","Nexus 7", ... ,"Android 4.4.3"
"7", ... ,"ozere Wireles","YP-GI1", ... ,"Android 2.3.6"
"34", ... ,"ivebox-7aa","GT-I9100", ... ,"Android 4.1.2"
"36", ... ,"Livebox-D244","Nexus 7", ... ,"Android 4.4.3"
"63", ... ,"pizzeria du midi","GT-I9505", ... ,"Android 4.4.2"
"72", ... ,"izzeria du mid","SM-T210", ... ,"Android 4.1.2"
```

So my problem is to guess on which rule the name is truncated?

-Edit-
I use the following code:

```
                WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)site.getMainActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlString);
                String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID().substring(1, wifiInfo.getSSID().length() - 1);
```

Well, after trying on a old device 2.3.6, I found that before the SSID name returned by getSSID() was not surrounded by "" which is the case on the last versions and the reason why I use substring().
So it's my fault!
Surrounding the SSID name by "" is quite strange anyway.

Comment: Maybe your application is broken. Post code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should use `replace()`.

```
String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID().replace("\"", "");
```